# Calling a python file of virtual environment from applescript

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, applescript, virtualenv

I have got an applescript and a python script.
The applescript should be the frame of the python script and should execute the python script.
The python script uses a python version and packages, that are saved in a virtual environment.

How can I make the applescript run the python script inside of the virtual environment, so that all the packages and python versions of this environment are used?

My way to do this without applescript was to type `source virtualenvironment/bin/activate` and after that `python /Users/abc/script.py` into the **terminal**.

Using the applescript command

```
do shell script "source virtualenvironment/bin/activate" 
do shell script "python /Users/abc/script.py"
```

does not work for me. Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *have* to activate a virtualenv; that mostly just sets your `PATH` environment variable so that when your shell looks up what executable to use for the `python` command, it finds `virtualenvironment/bin/python` before any other python executables. Just use the expanded, full path, so `/virtualenvironment/bin/python` instead of `python`:

```
do shell script "v/irtualenvironment/bin/python /Users/abc/script.py"
```

You can also make `/Users/abc/script.py` executable by making the first line a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) pointing to your virtualenv Python executable:

```
#!/virtualenvironment/bin/python
```

and setting the executable flag on the file (`chmod +x script.py`, from a terminal).